# Algorithm for finding distinct paths from A to B in weighted, directed, cyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding

Suppose we have a **DIRECTED**, **WEIGHTED** and **CYCLIC** graph.

Suppose we are only interested in paths with a **total weight of less than MAX_WEIGHT**

What is the most appropriate (or any) algorithm to find the **number of distinct paths** between two nodes A and B that have a total weight of less than MAX_WEIGHT?

P.S: It's not my homework. Just personal, non-commercial project.

Comment: Do you allow paths that visit the same vertex more than once (provided the length of the path is less than MAX_WEIGHT)?

Comment: Can we assume no zero-weight cycles?

Comment: @aix: Yes, sorry forgot to mention. You can loop around as much as you want as long as MAX_WEIGHT criteria is met.

Comment: @bdares: I'm not entirely sure what zero-weight cycle means. You can assume every edge has a weight greater than 0.

Comment: What's the meaning of `distinct paths`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of nodes and `MAX_WEIGHT` aren't too large (and all weights are integers), you can use dynamic programming

```
unsigned long long int num_of_paths[MAX_WEIGHT+1][num_nodes];
```

initialize to 0, except `num_of_paths[0][start] = 1;`.

```
for(w = 0; w < MAX_WEIGHT; ++w){
    for(n = 0; n < num_nodes; ++n){
        if (num_of_paths[w][n] > 0){
            /* for each child c of node n
             * if w + weight(n->c) <= MAX_WEIGHT
             * num_of_paths[w+weight(n->c)][c] += num_of_paths[w][n];
             */
        }
    }
}
```

solution is sum of `num_of_paths[w][target], 0 <= w <= MAX_WEIGHT` .

Comment: If you can solve it in this way you can solve k-disjoint path general case in O(n*MAX_WEIGHT) and if you assume all edges have weight `1`, you can solve it in O(n^3), but it is NP-hard in this case.

Comment: I fail to see how disjoint paths is relevant to the problem as stated.

Comment: This is part of question: "What is the most appropriate (or any) algorithm to find the `number of distinct paths` between two nodes A and B " and for more detail read my answer.

Comment: Err, `distinct != disjoint`. `A -> B -> C -> D` and `A -> C -> B -> D` are two distinct paths from `A` to `D`.

Comment: What you say is k-edge disjoint path problem. Also I don't think OP says so. Also in edge disjoint path again you can't do this.

Comment: @Saeed I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding. Of course it could be that I am, but I think it's you. I don't have any kind of disjointness in my algorithm, nor is any mentioned in the problem statement. A better example than the previous would probably be `A -> B -> D -> E` and `A -> C -> D -> E`. Those are two **distinct** paths from `A` to `E`, but they have vertices and edges in common.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6792/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 1):

Simple recursion. You have it in exponential time. Obviously, no zero-weight cycles allowed.

function noe(node N, limit weight W)

1. no. of path is zero if all outgoing edges have weight > W
2. otherwise no. of path is sum of numbers of path obtained by sum(noe(C1,W-W1),noe(C2,W-W2),... noe(Cn,W-Wn)) where C1 ... Cn are the nodes connected to N for which W-Wi is not negative where Wi is weight of the connecting edge, written in your favorite language.

More eficient solution should exist, along the lines of Dijkstra's algorithm, but I think this is enough for homework.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more general case of [K-Disjoint Path In directed planar graphs](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/fkdp.pdf), with not fixed K.

`K` disjoint paths problem for directed planar graphs is as this:

**given**: a directed planar graph G = (V;E) and k pairs (r<sub>1</sub>; s<sub>1</sub>); .... ; (r<sub>k</sub>; s<sub>k</sub>) of vertices of G;

**find**: k pairwise vertex-disjoint directed paths P<sub>1</sub>; ... ; P<sub>k</sub> in G, where P<sub>i</sub> runs from r<sub>i</sub> to s<sub>i</sub> (i = 1; .... ; k).

In k-disjoint path you can draw arc from all s<sub>i</sub> to B, and Also arc from A to all r<sub>i</sub> by this way you create graph G' from G.

Now if you can solve your problem in G' in **P** you can solve k-disjoint Path in G, So P=NP.

But if you read the paper linked it gives some idea for general graph (solving k-disjoint path with fixed k) and you can use it to have some good approximation.

Also there is more complicated algorithm which solves this problem in P (for fixed k) in general graphs. but in all it's not easy (it's by Seymour ).

So your best choice currently is to use brute force algorithms.

**Edit:** Because MAXWEIGHT is independent to your input size (your graph size) It doesn't affect to this problem, Also because it's NP-Hard for undirected unweighted graph, still you simply can conclude it's NP-Hard.

Comment: If you interested in more topic around this you can take a look at http://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/agt3.pdf